# IN query with DynamoDB table is not working

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

ScanRequest with IN on a list field is not matching with the entries in DynamoDB.
Code:

```
                Map<String, AttributeValue> userAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
                userAttributeValues.put(":topic1", new AttributeValue().withS("5"));
                userAttributeValues.put(":topic2", new AttributeValue().withS("11"));

                ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
                .withTableName("user")
                .withFilterExpression("subscribedTopics IN (:topic1, :topic2)")
                .withProjectionExpression("userId")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(userAttributeValues);

                ScanResult result = dynamoDBClient.scan(scanRequest);

                System.out.println("Number of results: " + result.getCount());

                for (Map<String, AttributeValue> userItemsMap : result.getItems()) {
                    AttributeValue userIdAttributeValue = userItemsMap.get("userId");
                    String userId = userIdAttributeValue.getS();
                }
```

User item with valid entry

{ "subscribedTopics": [ "2", "5", "8", "1", "3", "4", "6", "7", "11" ], "userId": "Andrew.Green" }

Comment: The list `[ "2", "5", "8", "1", "3", "4", "6", "7", "11" ]` is not `IN ("5","11")`. Perhaps you are looking for the `CONTAINS` operator?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am not into dynamo db much. In mongodb, the IN clause works like this. How can i achieve this with CONTAINS? Does contains accept more than one attribute value?

Comment: @RealSkeptic ok. I used CONTAINS and OR, got the results. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used combination of CONTAINS and OR and it worked.

```
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
.withTableName("user")
.withFilterExpression("contains(subscribedTopics, :topic1) or contains(subscribedTopics, :topic2)")
.withProjectionExpression("userId")
.withExpressionAttributeValues(userAttributeValues);enter code here
```